# How to add in Django a non-nullable ForeignKey to an existing table?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=80, ...)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=80, ....)
```

And I want to add a non-nullable foreign key as shown here:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=80, ....)
    parent = ForeignKey(parent)
```

Both tables already exists in the database but have no data.

When running *makemigrations* Django asks for a default value. If I don't want to provide a default value, is it better to perform 2 migrations, the first one with *null=True* and then run a second one with *null=False*, before ingesting data in the DDBB?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running two migrations would not solve anything. While running second migration you would get again warning that you have to provide a default value.

What is your intention with the existing Child instances? How do you plan to fill the parent column?

Comment: 1) What is your intention with the existing Child instances? I want to create the relationship between the two models.  2) How do you plan to fill the parent column?: Since both tables are empty, once the migrations are done, I will include the logic to meet this requirement.

Comment: Ok, then you while running your original migration Django offers an option to leave the existing rows empty. If you do so, the application will not run correctly until you fill the values yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no data in both the tables then it does not matter what you select to provide one-off default value just set it to 1 (in case of foreign key it works as ID, but as there is no data it does not matter).

If there is data in those tables then you have to do a 2 step migration first with `null=True`, then migrate data in migration script and then set it to `null=False`.